# Solution of a simple integral equation

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, integral-equations

I have the following integral equation:
$$
f(x)=\exp{\left(-\int_{-x}^{\infty}f(y)\,dy\right)}\,\,,
$$
where a condition on $f(x)$ holds:
$$
f(x=0)=\frac{1}{2}\,.
$$
I know that the solution is:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{x}}
$$
but how can I show this (without knowing the solution)? I'm also interested in solving this equation using a software like Mathematica.

Comment: We are not allowed to provide you an answer because [you did not show enough work](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). However, here are big hints: differentiate your integral equation, notice that $f'$ must be even, use this to eliminate $f(-x)$, solve the resulting [Bernoulli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation), plug the solution $f(x)=\frac1{1+ae^{bx}}$ into your initial equation and determine the *two* solutions $(a,b).$

Comment: You can also take the derivative twice and conclude $\left(\frac{f'}{f}\right)' = \frac{f'}{f}$

Comment: Great work on giving the Answer/Hint which made OP work-out the Solution , @AnneBauval , the Credit should go to you !

Comment: @Giancarlo I upvoted your answer. If you feel like, you can upvote one of mine.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this solution thanks to one of the comments.

I differentiate both side:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\exp{\left( -\int_{-x}^{\infty}f(y)\,dy\right)}\quad \Rightarrow \quad f'(x)=-f(-x)f(x)\,.
$$
This equation implies that $f'(x)$ is an even function of $x$, which in turn implies:
$$
f(-x)+c=-(f(x)+c)\quad \Rightarrow \quad f(-x)=-f(x)-2c\,,
$$
where $c$ is a constant (that will be fixed imposing the last property at the end of the computation). Substituting this result in the differential equation for $f(x)$ I have
$$
f'(x)=f(x)\big(2c+f(x)\big)\,.
$$
This first-order non-linear differential equation can be solved by separation of variables:
$$
\int \frac{1}{f(2c+f)}df=\int dx \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{1}{2c}\ln{\left(\frac{f}{2c+f}\right)} + K = x
$$
where $K$ is a constant of integration that can be computed imposing that $f(0)=1/2$. With simple algebra it is possible to express $f$ as a function of $x$, depending also on the constants $c$ and $K'$ ($K'$ is another constant which depends on $K$ and can be found manipulating the previous equation for $f$):
$$
f(x)=\frac{2c}{e^{-2cx}K'-1}\,.
$$
Imposing $f(x=0)=1/2$, $K'$ can be fixed: $K'=4c+1$. At this point is possible to fix also $c$ imposing $f(-x)=-f(x)-2c$ for a simple value of $x$ (since this relation must hold for every value of $x\in\mathbb{R}$), for instance $x=0$, which leads to $c=-1/2$ and, finally:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{x}}\,.
$$

Comment: Excellent job! (You even corrected my calculation mistake claiming $f(x)=\frac1{1+ae^{bx}}$ instead of $\frac b{1+ae^{bx}}$. ) I was also wrong when believing  that $a=-1$ also gave solutions (even before you edited your question to add the constraing $f(0)=1/2$). It does not work because it is not defined for $x=0.$
 You can improve your question and answer by giving the solutions *without your later additional constraint*: $f(x)=\frac1{1+e^{bx}}.$