# Second (and Third) Order Non-linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, systems-of-equations

I want to solve the following equation for $f(x)$ (where $f: \mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^+$):
$$
f(x)=\exp{\left(-\int_{-x}^{\infty}(y+x)^rf(y)\,dy\right)}\,\,,
$$
where $r\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f(-\infty)=1$ and $f(+\infty)=0$. I am interested in particular in the cases $r=1$ and $r=2$.

I can manipulate the equation by defining an auxiliary function $a(x)$:
$$
a(x)\equiv \ln{f(x)}\,,\quad \text{where} \quad a(-\infty)=0\,;
$$
deriving both sides I get:
$$
a'(x)=-r\int_{-x}^{\infty}dy(y+x)^{(r-1)} e^{a(y)}\,.
$$

#### Case $r=1$:

Deriving another time both sides I get the following second order non-linear differential equation:
$$
a''(x)=-e^{a(-x)}\,.
$$
Defining $b(x)\equiv a(-x)$, it is possible to write a system of two differential equations
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll} a''(x)=-e^{b(x)} &  \\ b''(x)=-e^{a(x)} &  \end{array}\right.
$$
where some conditions must be imposed: $a(0)=b(0)$, $a(-\infty)=0$, $a'(-\infty)=0$ and $-a'(0)=b'(0)$.

#### Case $r=2$:

In this case I derive both sides twice to get:
$$
a'''(x)=-2e^{a(-x)}\,.
$$
In the same spirit of the $r=1$ case we can use $b(x)$ to write:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll} a'''(x)=-2e^{b(x)} &  \\ b'''(x)=2e^{a(x)} &  \end{array}\right.
$$
where now the conditions to be imposed are: $a(0)=b(0)$, $a(-\infty)=0$, $a'(-\infty)=0$, $a''(-\infty)=0$, $-a'(0)=b'(0)$ and $a''(0)=b''(0)$.

This idea to manipulate these equations can be generalized to arbitrary $r$ and it is due to @yarchik from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287334/solution-of-an-integral-equation) question about numerical solutions. Is there a way to analytically deal with these equations?

The present question is also related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728120/solution-of-a-simple-integral-equation) one, which is the case $r=0$, that is analytically solvable.